# Android Soap Request in WCF

Tags: c#, android, wcf, soap

How to request this xml in Soap Android for WCF.
This is from WCF Test Client

```
<LoginNew xmlns="http://192.168.10.60/Services/">
  <Username xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Password i:nil="true" />
    <Username i:nil="true" />
    <VersionCode>0</VersionCode>
  </Username>
</LoginNew>
</s:Body>
```

i tried this already but no hope . its return null in WCF

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "LoginNew");
    SoapObject UsernamePassword = new SoapObject();
    UsernamePassword.addProperty("Username", "arlind");
    UsernamePassword.addProperty("Password", "arlind");
    request.addSoapObject(UsernamePassword);

    <s:Body>
```

My Wcf code:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               UriTemplate = "/LoginNew")]
    string LoginNew(UsernamePassword Username);



    public class UsernamePassword
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int VersionCode { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining that the Content-type accepted by your WCF endpoint is application/Json here

```
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
```

so probably start by changing it to WebMessageFormat.Xml

Secondly, I believe that in order for your WCF service to accept SOAP messages, you'll also have to have your service configured for basicHttpBinding for SOAP 1.1 or wsHttpBinding for SOAP 1.2

Comment: Im receiving soap request but its null, and i dont need to accept XML , i need soap.